# JavaScript HTML -- How can I implement gravity/jumping into my basic game?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a basic game. I currently have an object (box4) that moves left and right using Keycode Events. But I want to add Gravity. I'm not sure how to go about this; everything I've found online isn't directly implementable verbatim in my game. Usually because it's entirely inline and isn't object-oriented whatsoever (I'm using classes/inheritance), but also because I'm a newbie.

Here's what my code looks like:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <script src="sprites/box.js"></script>
    <script src="sprites/box2.js"></script>
    <script src="sprites/box3.js"></script>
    <script src="sprites/box4.js"></script>
    <script src="sprites/arrow.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            //get the canvas
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
                //get the context
                context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                //create an arrow object
                arrow = new Arrow(),
                //create a box object
                box = new Box();
                box2 = new Box2();
                box3 = new Box3();
                box4 = new Box4();
                var gravity = 0.5;
            //position the box at 80,40 on the canvas
            box.X = 80;
            box.Y = 40;
            box2.X = 80;
            box2.Y = 40;
            box3.X = 150;
            box3.Y = 150;
            box4.X = 200;
            box4.Y = 200;
            //position the arrow at 300,300 (middle of the canvas)
            arrow.X = 300;
            arrow.Y = 300;

            //draw the first frame
            drawFrame();

            //fucntion for drawing the frames
            function drawFrame() {
                //clear the canvas
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                //increase the y posn by the y velocity
                box.Y += box.VY;
                //increase the x posn by the x velocity
                box.X += box.VX;
                //increase the y posn by the y velocity
                box2.Y += box2.VY;
                //increase the x posn by the x velocity
                box2.X += box2.VX;
                //increase the y posn by the y velocity
                box3.Y += box3.VY;
                //increase the x posn by the x velocity
                box3.X += box3.VX;

                window.onkeydown = function (e) {
                    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
                    if (code === 37) { //left key
                        box4.X -= box4.VX;
                    } else if (code === 38) {
                        box4.Y -= 20;
                    } else if (code === 39) { //right key
                        box4.X += box4.VX;
                    } else if (code === 40) {
                        box4.Y += 20;
                    } else if (code === 32) {
                        box4.Y -= 20;
                    }
                };

                //if the box hits the canvas top bottom edge
                if (box.Y - box.Size < 0 | box.Y + box.Size > canvas.height) {
                    //reverse the y velocity
                    box.VY = -box.VY;
                }
                //if the box hits the canvas left or right
                if (box.X - box.Size < 0 | box.X + box.Size > canvas.width) {
                    //reverse the x velocity
                    box.VX = -box.VX;
                }
                if (box2.Y - box2.Size < 0 | box2.Y + box2.Size > canvas.height) {
                    box2.VY = -box2.VY;
                }
                if (box2.X - box2.Size < 0 | box2.X + box2.Size > canvas.width) {
                    box2.VX = -box2.VX;
                }
                if (box3.Y - box3.Size < 0 | box3.Y + box3.Size > canvas.height) {
                    box3.VY = -box3.VY;
                }
                if (box3.X - box3.Size < 0 | box3.X + box3.Size > canvas.width) {
                    box3.VX = -box3.VX;
                }
                //calculate the difference between the box x position and the arrow x position
                var dx = box.X - arrow.X;
                //calculate the difference between the box y position and the arrow y position
                var dy = box.Y - arrow.Y;
                //set the angle of rotation for the arrow
                arrow.Rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                //draw the box
                box.draw(context);
                box2.draw(context);
                box3.draw(context);
                box4.draw(context);
                //request the next frame
                window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Box4 class:

```
function Box4() {
    //private data members
    //x posn
    var x = 0,
    //y posn
    y = 0,
    //colour
    colour = "red",
    //size
    size = 20,
    //x velocity
    vx = 4,
    //y velocity
    vy = 4;

    //public property for VX
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'VX',
    {
        get: function () {
            return vx;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            vx = value;
        }
    }
    )

    //public property for VY
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'VY',
    {
        get: function () {
            return vy;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            vy = value;
        }
    }
    )

    //public property for size
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'Size',
    {
        get: function () {
            return size;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            size = value;
        }
    }
    )

    //public property for X
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'X',
    {
        get: function () {
            return x;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            x = value;
        }
    }
    )

    //public property for Y
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'Y',
    {
        get: function () {
            return y;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            y = value;
        }
    }
    )

    //function public draw method
    Box4.prototype.draw = function (context) {
        //save the context
        context.save();
        //set x and y
        context.translate(x, y);
        //set the line width
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        //set the colour of the fill
        context.fillStyle = colour;
        //begin the path
        context.beginPath();
        //draw the box
        context.moveTo(-size, -size);
        context.lineTo(-size, size);
        context.lineTo(size, size);
        context.lineTo(size, -size);
        //close the path
        context.closePath();
        //fill the shape
        context.fill();
        //draw it
        context.stroke();
        //restore the context
        context.restore();
    };

}
```

My program to download: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=87972197214078945115

Does anyone know any workarounds that would work easily with my current code and code structure?

Comment: Well, normally you should just implement a velocity change (i.e. acceleration) in the negative y direction during your main loop... For reference: Earth gravity accelerates a body by about 9.81 m/s^2

Comment: It looks like you have all the building blocks for a simple physics simulation: objects with position, velocity, and size properties, and a game loop where you modify velocities & positions prior to a display update. This looks like it should match up pretty much exactly with most beginner tutorials on the subject. But you say you haven't found *anything* online that matches up? It might help if you include a sample of a guide you're trying to follow, and highlight where you're running into trouble with it, so we can target our explanation toward this specific issue or gap.